# Execute string as SQL query in C

Tags: sql, c, oracle, execute

it's possible to execute a string as a SQL query in C and get the result? I'm trying to compile this code:

```
EXEC SQL
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE : sql_formula INTO :sql_prec_desconto_mp;
```

But I've this error:

> Error at line 10548, column 35 in file
>
> D:\syncs\AIX\fuentes\funcn\niv2\src\rutin as.pc
>
> ```
>             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE : sql_formula INTO :sql_prec_desconto_mp;
> ```
>
> PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the
> following:
>
> ; ( [ . ++ -- ->

How can I get the result of the SQL query? If I remove the INTO clause I can compile without errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is [described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_afemb.htm#CHEGFGJB):

> To prepare and execute a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement or a PL/SQL block containing no host variables.

You aren't doing one of those DML types, and those don't recognise `INTO`. When you run a dynamic SQL query without an `INTO` the query is never actually executed ([see the note in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201)).

The quickest way that immediately comes to mind to do what I think you want, is to prepare a cursor and fetch the result:

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE stmt FROM :sql_formula;
EXEC SQL DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR stmt;
EXEC SQL OPEN cur;
EXEC SQL FETCH cur INTO :sql_prec_desconto_mp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that code solved my problem! :)